# How to send the PDF output to browser print option (CTRL+P)

Tags: printing, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF library to generate some reports, and i want to send the PDF file to print option of browser as simple we press CTRL+P, I need this because it is slip.
I used all parameter for Output but it is downloading the file directly.

```
$pdf->Output('slip.pdf', 'I');
```

I also placed the F,D,S,E,FI and FD instate of I but it doesn't work. And I also used header

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
$pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'FD');
```

but again it doesn't work. Any solution? Please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need something like the example below. You would need to intercept print request (print automatically on page load, print button click, etc.) and then call printTrigger function.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Print PDF</title>
    <script>
        function printTrigger(elementId) {
            var getMyFrame = document.getElementById(elementId);
            getMyFrame.focus();
            getMyFrame.contentWindow.print();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe id="iFramePdf" src="http://pdfurl.com/sample.pdf"></iframe>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

Add 
     `$pdf->IncludeJS("print();");`
just before $pdf->Output...

Comment: simple, smart solution. saved my time :)

Comment: Do you mean $pdf->Output('slip.pdf', 'I'); or $pdf->Output('slip.pdf', 'F');

Comment: @Jarla before both $pdf->Output

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not within the specification of the TCPDF API.

http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a3d6dcb62298ec9d42e9125ee2f5b23a1

I believe you would need to use JavaScript to implement this feature the way you are proposing.

Comment: but i don't have idea about javascript

Answer (score -2):

Add $pdf->IncludeJS("print();"); just before $pdf->Output...
It's working for me.

Comment: Do you mean $pdf->Output('slip.pdf', 'I'); or $pdf->Output('slip.pdf', 'F');